# Updating Page Items with Respect to Filters in Oracle APEX Interactive Report

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I've recently started using Interactive Reports in my Oracle APEX application. Previously, all pages in the application used Classic Reports. The Interactive Report in my new page works great, but, now, I'd like to add a summary box/table above the Interactive Report on the same page that displays the summed values of some of the columns in the Interactive Report. In other words, if my Interactive Report displays 3 distinct manager names, 2 distinct office locations, and 5 different employees, my summary box would contain one row and three columns with the numbers, 3, 2, and 5, respectively.

So far, I have made this work by creating the summary box as a Classic Report that counts distinct values for each column in the same table that my Interactive Report pulls from. The problem arises when I try to filter my interactive report. Obviously, the classic report doesn't refresh based on the interactive report filters, but I don't know how I could link the two so that the classic report responds to the filters from the interactive report. Based on my research, there are ways to reference the value in the Interactive Report's search box using javascript/jquery. If possible, I'd like to reference the value from the interactive table's filter with javascript or jquery in order to refresh the summary box each time a new filter is applied. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Just don't. Honestly. If only it was for the reason apex 5 is around the corner and everything you create will be obsolete then. Why do you need this? Is it some sort of requirement? This is likely not the way you want to solve it due to the massive overhead it will create.

Comment: It was a requirement from my client to include the summary. The only way I could think to do this would be through a separate classic report at the top of the page. Would there be a way to create a similar summary within an Interactive Report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do javascript parsing on the filters. It's a bad idea - just think on how you would implement this? There's massive amounts of coding to be done and plenty of ajax. And with apex 5 literally around the corner, where does it leave you when the APIs and markup are about to change drastically?

---

Don't just give in to a requirement either. First make sure how feasible it is technically. And if it's not, make sure you make it abundantly clear what the implications are in regard of time consumption. What is the real value to be had by having these distinct value counts? Maybe there is another way to achieve what they want? Maybe this is nothing more than an attempted solution, and not the core of the real problem. Stuff to think about...

---

Having said that, here are 2 options:

### First method: Count Distinct Aggregates on Interactive reports

[image: interactive report with count distinct aggregates applied]

You can add these to the IR through the Actions button.
[image: aggregate location under the actions button]

[image: aggregate definition]

**Note though, that this aggregate will be THE LAST ROW!** In the example I've posted here, reducing the rows per page to 5 would push the aggregate row to the pagination set 3!

---

### Second Method: APEX_IR and DBMS_SQL

You could use the apex_ir API to retrieve the IR's query and then use that to do a count.
[(Apex 4.2) APEX_IR.GET_REPORT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_ir.htm#AEAPI29379)
[(Apex 5.0) APEX_IR.GET_REPORT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_ir.htm#AEAPI29379)

Some pointers:
Retrieve the region ID by querying apex_application_page_regions

Make sure your source query **DOES NOT** contain `#...#` substitution strings. (such as `#OWNER#`.)

Then get the report SQL, rewrite it, and execute it. Eg:

```
DECLARE
   l_report apex_ir.t_report;
   l_query varchar2(32767);

  l_statement varchar2(32000);
  l_cursor integer;
  l_rows number;
  l_deptno number;
  l_mgr number;
BEGIN 
    l_report := APEX_IR.GET_REPORT (
                    p_page_id => 30,
                    p_region_id => 63612660707108658284,
                    p_report_id => null);
    l_query := l_report.sql_query;
    sys.htp.prn('Statement = '||l_report.sql_query);
    for i in 1..l_report.binds.count
    loop
        sys.htp.prn(i||'. '||l_report.binds(i).name||' = '||l_report.binds(i).value);
    end loop;

    l_statement := 'select count (distinct deptno), count(distinct mgr) from ('||l_report.sql_query||')';

    sys.htp.prn('statement rewrite: '||l_statement);

 l_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(l_cursor, l_statement, dbms_sql.native);

    for i in 1..l_report.binds.count
    loop
      dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cursor, l_report.binds(i).name, l_report.binds(i).value);
    end loop;

    dbms_sql.define_column(l_cursor, 1, l_deptno);
    dbms_sql.define_column(l_cursor, 2, l_mgr);

    l_rows := dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch(l_cursor);

    dbms_sql.column_value(l_cursor, 1, l_deptno);
    dbms_sql.column_value(l_cursor, 2, l_mgr);

    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cursor);

    sys.htp.prn('Distinct deptno: '||l_deptno);
    sys.htp.prn('Distinct mgr: '||l_mgr);
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF DBMS_SQL.IS_OPEN(l_cursor) THEN
      DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor);
    END IF;
    RAISE;
END;
```

I threw together the sample code from apex_ir.get_report and dbms_sql .
[Oracle 11gR2 DBMS_SQL reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sql.htm)

Some serious caveats though: the column list is tricky. If a user has control of all columns and can remove some, those columns will disappear from the select list. Eg in my sample, letting the user hide the DEPTNO column would crash the entire code, because I'd still be doing a count of this column even though it will be gone from the inner query. You could block this by not letting the user control this, or by first parsing the statement etc...

---

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, the second method works great! The APEX_IR or DBMS_SQL packages are awesome! I printed the results to the page using an APEX page item. I will format those to look like a summary box. I also tried putting the code into the source of a classic report. I was using the l_statement string as the return string, but every time I tried saving the report, the APEX_IR.GET_REPORT query would execute on the workspace and generate an error message telling me that the report ID was not found on that page in Application 4000 (my workspace application ID). Have you encountered this before?

Comment: You mean you get an error when saving the report? Or when executing it?

Comment: @jobrien9 Right, after trying I understand. Apex will run the code in an attempt to parse the statement and determine the columns. Obviously this fails. The statement should only be run at runtime, much like a PLSQL process does. In order to do that, you need to set the `Use generic column names` property to `yes`, as this wil tell apex to only parse the statement at runtime. Downside is that you will only have "generic" column names (`COL1, COL2, COL3,...`) though you can still control the column heading. However. Even though it'll validate, at runtime it'll still not work!

Comment: @jobrien9 It doesn't, because there are binds which are simply not available through the session state. For example, applying a filter will require an additional bind such as `APXWS_EXPR_1`, or simply the always-present `APXWS_MAX_ROW_CNT` variable. These are not in the general session state, they're only there in scope of an IR region. In the PLSQL process it works because we're explicitly setting the session state with the provided binds. In a report region we can't do this.

Comment: @jobrien9 However - if you're really interested in doing this in a report region, you can take a look at a pipelined function, which in short is a function which 'streams' rows, and you can select from. In there you could write the plsql code to parse and execute the statement such as in the process code, and return those as rows.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Since my report is small enough, I ended up executing the code in a "before page load process". I saved each of the output values in which I was interested to hidden APEX items and had the report select each of the hidden APEX items in its source code.